# How to install VirtualBox guest additions on Fedora 14 guest?

Tags: linux, virtualization, fedora

I installed a Fedora 14 guest on a Fedora 14 host with Virtualbox, then i run these commands on the guest:

```
yum install kernel-devel kernel-headers
```

but if i try to install the virtualbox-guest additions on the guest, is still complains about that it's unable to find the kernel source directory?

Ha anyone succeded installing the guest additions on a guest Fedora 14?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There should be a reasonable description of the problem that Virtualbox had in the file

> /var/log/vboxadd-install.log

so have a look there and see if you can find something useful to help you.

One thing you may want to check is that the source matches the kernel you have installed (you can use the command `uname -r` to check which kernel you are actually running).

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have the updated kernel.

```
yum -y update kernel
```

This is just to make sure you install the guest additions on the latest kernel image.

Also make sure you have any other necessary packages:

```
yum -y install kernel-devel kernel-headers dkms gcc gcc-c++
```

Also to access kernel source directories you will need to go to:

```
/usr/src/kernels/
```

Get the correct kernel source folder as there may be different folders, make sure you have the latest version pointed out.

Hope some of these pointers help.